# want to preload an image for some time before getJson call

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, getjson, preloading

I am using a getJson call for drop downs. I want to have an image preloading effect for this ajax call.
Can any one help me out with this...??
My code follows:

```
$.getJSON("myAction.do?method=fetchThruAJAX", {
    TypeNo: $("#Type").val(),
    ajax: 'true'
}, function(j) {
    var options = '<option selected value="-1">---Select---</option>';
    if (j != null) {
        $.each(j.Model, function(i, item) {
            options += '<option value="' + item.SeqNo + '">'
                + item.Name + '</option>';
        });
    }
    $("select#Model").html(options);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do that globally using the [ajaxStart](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStart/) and [ajaxStop](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/) events:

```
$("#yourEffectContainerID").ajaxStart(function() {
    $(this).fadeIn("fast");
}).ajaxStop(function() {
    $(this).fadeOut("fast");
});
```

That way, your effect container will be displayed during *all* AJAX requests (so that behavior is not limited to the specific `getJSON()` call you issue for your dropdown).

Comment: Hi thanks for the reply. I am declaring it gloabally like: '$(document).ready(function() { $("#imageLoad").ajaxStart(function() { $(this).fadeIn("fast"); }) .ajaxStop(function() { $(this).fadeOut("fast"); }); })' and have my div container like '<div id="imageLoad" style="display:none"><img src="images/108.gif" ></img></div>' But the code which you gave isn't working. I think i am doing it some where wrong. Please help me if you have some example code to get a better picture on this

Comment: @frederic: but isn't it a bit too fast. I am trying now with slow one, lets see....!!! or cant we show the image for say some 2 seconds than hide it...???

Comment: @rahul, see the documentation for the first argument to [fadeIn()](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/). You can specify the effect duration as a string or a integer (expressed in milliseconds).

Comment: I will tell what actually the mistake was.
I made that div but it was neither in a ts nor in a tr but between a tr with out a td so it dint work. But now it is working. :):) thank you so much. People will surely learn from this fault i did. I think so..!!!

Comment: hey frederic do you have any example to put this effect in an grey-overlay, so that it looks good..??
Please suggest soon that would surely help.

Comment: @rahul, well, I'm not sure what you mean by `grey-overlay`, but I'd suggest you ask another SO question about that effect with all the gory details :)